# Open window within main window PyQt5

Tags: qt, window, pyqt5

I'm trying to open another window within my main window using createWindowContainer, but it's just opening the window without embedding it.
I wasn't able to find an example of how to use createWindowContainer for python to check if I am using the function correctly. I got what I have by deciphering the c++ code for createWindowContainer and Qt documentation:
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#createWindowContainer
I tried to simplify the code to isolate the function to figure out how it should be properly used, but it doesn't seem to matter whether or not I have the line:

```
QtWidgets.QWidget.createWindowContainer(window,self)
```

Here is the full code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui
import time
import QtDesigner

class MainUiClass(QtGui.QMainWindow,QtDesigner.Ui_MainWindow):
     def __init__(self,parent=None):
          super(MainUiClass,self).__init__(parent)
          self.setupUi(self)
          self.btn.pressed.connect(self.openWindow)
     def openWindow(self):
          window=Window()
          QtWidgets.QWidget.createWindowContainer(window,self)
          time.sleep(0.1)
          window.show()

 class Window(QtGui.QWindow):
     def __init__(self,parent=None):
          super(Window,self).__init__(parent)

 if __name__=='__main__':
      app=QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
      GUI=MainUiClass()
      GUI.show()
      app.exec_()
```

Comment: Note that you're not actually *using* the `QWidget` returned by `createWindowContainer`.  Try adding it to a layout in your main window's central widget or similar.

Comment: Unrelated: PySide is a much more "pythonic" QT integration. It's also officially supported (not sure, but I think I read an article it is supposed to replace PyQT in the future)..